# RSpec: testing large hashes in RSpec

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec

I'm trying to write a test for a simple hash however the hash itself is quite large.

For a smaller has I might write a test like so:

```
describe Hash do
  it 'should display some kind if hash' do
    some_hash = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
    expect(subject.hash).to eq some_hash
  end
end
```

However for a large has where it may seem cumbersome to do the above (i.e. for a has with twenty or so key-value pairs) what's the best way to write the test?

thanks for your help

Comment: Didn't get you.. Can you tell what do you mean by *However for a large has where it may seem cumbersome to do the above* ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of your hash, you may consider using fixtures: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

Or you can just store .yml file in the let's say 'support' directory under specs and load the hash into a variable like this:

```
my_hash = YAML.load_file('path_to_yml.yml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are two ways to go about this, one way is to write out the whole hash and expect it to be equal to, like you are doing above. The second way would be to expect the hash to include a certain value.

```
expect(subject.hash).to include(:one)
```

You will probably be generating this hash from multiple methods inside the class it is being used. It would be better to test the methods that are used to create the hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting that the hash contains x keys but you are not concerned about the values at this stage, then you could do:

```
keys_array = [:a, :b, :c, ... :n]`
expect(subject.hash.keys).to eq keys_array
```

However, if your class is something like:

```
class Foo
  ...

  def to_h
    # call other methods and combine into a hash
  end
  ...

end
```

and there is non-trivial amount of logic within each of these methods, then you may be better off testing each of the methods individually.

Alternatively, you might only care that each of the keys returns some value (rather than `nil`):

`expect(subject.hash.values).to_not include(nil)`

Answer (score 0):

If the test only cares about some values in the resulting hash, you don't need to explicitly indicate any other elements in the hash, which are not relevant to the test using `include`:

```
describe Hash do
  it 'should display some kind if hash' do
    some_hash = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
    expect(subject.hash).to include some_hash
  end
end
```

You might decide to create several tests, each testing a different part of the resulting hash.

If your test needs to validate *all* elements are *exactly* as expected, you'd need to explicitly create that hash. You might decide to write it in an external location (like a configuration file, or as a constant), especially if it is reused in more than one test.